# ffmpeg - copying original audio to second audio track, then applying filter to only first audio track

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video

I have a volume and audio channel problem with captures of videotapes that I'd like to fix in as non-destructive a way as possible. I've decided to go with applying a volume increase rather than normalisation. I realise now that I could keep the original audio in the container, and this would allow me to be reassured that the original unaltered audio still exists and is easily accessible.

This is what I have now:

`ffmpeg -i "input.avi" -filter_complex "[0:a]channelsplit=channel_layout=stereo:channels=FL,volume=+16.2dB[left]" -map "[left]" -map 0:v -c:v ffv1 -coder 1 -context 1 -g 1 -slices 24 -slicecrc 1 "output.mkv"`

The first filter is to use the left audio track to create one mono track. This is because the tapes are mono, and my capture device has no ability to capture straight to mono, so the right track is entirely blank, causing the dreaded "left ear only" audio issue.

The second filter is the volume increase.

How do I modify command to copy the original unedited audio from the capture file to the output file's audio track 2 as backup, *then* apply the filters to the output file's audio track 1 only?

Answer (score 1):

Map the input audio twice, and set codec option for 2nd audio track to `copy`.

`ffmpeg -i "input.avi" -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 0:a -filter:a:0 "channelsplit=channel_layout=stereo:channels=FL,volume=+16.2dB" -c:v ffv1 -coder 1 -context 1 -g 1 -slices 24 -slicecrc 1 -c:a:1 copy "output.mkv"`